# How to add constraint on associated type in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

I am trying to create a protocol `R` with an array of objects `n` which can be, in principle, different classes (`N1`, `N2`) but all subjects of the same protocol `N`. Classes that submit to the protocol `R` (`M1`, `M2`) can decide whether their property array `n` will hold only specific kind of `R` or any.

This compiles just fine:

```
protocol N { }
class N1: N { }
class N2: N { }

protocol R {
    associatedtype NType
    var n: [NType] { get set }
}

class M1: R {
    var n: [N] = [N1(), N2()]
}

class M2: R {
    var n: [N1] = [N1(), N1()]
}
```

But I don't understand how to add a constraint to the associatedtype `Ntype` that it must conform to `N`. Something in the lines of

```
protocol N { }
class N1: N { }
class N2: N { }

protocol R {
    associatedtype NType: N
    var n: [NType] { get set }
}

class M1: R {
    var n: [N] = [N1(), N2()]
}

class M2: R {
    var n: [N1] = [N1(), N1()]
}
```

This doesn't compile saying that `Type 'M1' does not conform to protocol 'R'`.

Comment: You can make `N` an `@objc` protocol. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) for more info.

Comment: Or skip the associated type and declare n as `var n: [N] { get set }` although then you must always implement `n` exactly as that.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, your method works!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson As you commented yourself the solution is not optimal because then `M2` can't have property `n` stored as `[N1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using swift 5.7.1 you can use `[any N]` I would not change `N`, `N1`, `N2` or `R`:

```swift
protocol N { }
class N1: N { }
class N2: N { }

protocol R {
    associatedtype NType
    var n: [NType] { get set }
}
```

But I would implement `M1` differently using and array of `any N` eg.:

```swift
class M1: R {
    var n: [any N] = [N1(), N2()]
}
```

which compiles and prints:

```swift
let m1 = M1()
print(m1.n) // [__lldb_expr_13.N1, __lldb_expr_13.N2]
m1.n.append(N2()) // [N1, N2, N2]
m1.n.append(N1()) // [N1, N2, N2, N1]
```

but it can also hold a specific kind of `N`, eg.:

```swift
class M2: R {
    var n: [N1] = [N1(), N1()]
}
```

which outputs:

```swift
let m2 = M2()
print(m2.n) // [__lldb_expr_17.N1, __lldb_expr_17.N1]
m2.n.append(N1()) // [N1, N1, N1]
m2.n.append(N2()) // No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'
```

as you can see `m1.n` is an heterogeneous array of objects conforming to `NType` aka `N` while `m2.n` can only hold `N1` values.

Comment: This is true and I have already provided this solution in the first code snippet in the question. What I would like to know is how to add constraint on NType that it must conform to protocol N, which now that I ask it like that, requires a protocol to conform to itself, which I know is not allowed. But maybe there is a way by restructuring the code or something. I know that it works if I convert `N` to a class, but this is not an ideal solution.

Comment: I don't see `[any N]` in you code snippets, `Any N` means any type conforming to `N` and it looks like what you are looking for. Anyway this is the way I would _restructure_ the code. I edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: But using this solution I must force  cast `n` to `[any N]` if I only know that an instance is conforming to protocol `R` but not necessarily which class it is. In other words, you do not answer the question on how to add constraint on `Ntype` so that it conforms to `N`.

Comment: Here you have a protocol R with an array of objects `n` which can be, in principle, different classes (`N1`, `N2`) but all subjects of the same protocol `N`. Classes that submit to the protocol `R` (`M1`, `M2`) can decide whether their property array `n` will hold only specific kind of `N` or `any N`. Can you explain why you need to force cast?

Comment: "Here you have a protocol R with an array of objects `n` which can be, in principle, different classes (`N1`, `N2`) but all subjects of the same protocol `N`." Where exactly is this constraint placed in your code? Let's say I create an array `r: [any R]` and an element of `r` will know that it has a property called `n` of type `[NType]`, but `NType` is at this point undefined, i. e. `Any`.  I can cast it to `[N]` but I want to avoid it.